# Dimension of symmetric $SU(2)$ invariant bilinear forms.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups

I am given the representation $\rho: SU(2) \rightarrow GL(V)$, (with $V \cong \mathbb{C}^7 $) and I know that the representation is isomorphic to $V_3 \oplus V_1 \oplus V_0$, where $V_n$ is the unique $(n+1)$ dimensional, complex irreducible representation of $SU(2)$.

Consider the space of symmetric, invariant bilinear forms, i.e. symmetric bilinear maps $B$ on $V \times V$ s.t. $\forall A \in SU(2): \  B(\rho(A)u, \rho(A)v)= B(u,v)$. I‘m supposed to find the dimension of this space.

I think that every bilinear form has a matrix representation, s.t. $B(u,v)=u^TBv$, (the $B$ on the right side is this corresponding matrix, excuse my abuse of notation). Now the invariance condition can be written as: $\rho(A)^TB\rho(A)=B \Leftrightarrow B\rho(A)=\rho({A^T}^{-1})B=\rho(\bar{A})B$. Now if I didn’t have that annoying complex conjugate, I could say that according to Schur‘s Lemma $B$ must be the identity on each $V_i$ and therefore the dimension must be 3 (since $\rho \circ B = B \circ \rho$). But I don’t now how to proceed in this case.

Comment: A bilinear form $B:V\times V\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is by definition of tensor product is an element of $V^*\otimes V^*$. You are interested in the fixed points of the action of $SU(2)$ on $V^*\otimes V^*$. There is a simple formula that explains how the tensor product of two $SU(2)$ splits into irreducibles.

Comment: I know the Clebsch-Gordan stuff, but I don‘t know how to apply it to the dual spaces, I will look it up!

Comment: $SU(2)$ representations are self-dual, hence you can just ignore $^*$s.

Comment: So $V^* \otimes V^* \cong V_6 \otimes V_6 \cong V_{12} \oplus V_{10} \oplus V_8 \oplus V_6 \oplus V_4 \oplus V_2 \oplus V_0$ and since I only want the symmetric ones probably only these are relevant: $V_{12} \oplus V_8 \oplus V_4 \oplus V_0$. How would I argue now? Only vectors in $V_0$ are fixed points under the action, and therefore the dimension is 1?

Comment: $V^*\cong V_6$ does not seem correct. Your vector space is $V=V_3\oplus V_1\oplus V_0$ so $V\otimes V= (V_3\oplus V_1\oplus V_0)\otimes (V_3\oplus V_1\oplus V_0)$. Note that the tensor product distributes over the sum. By Clebsch-Gordan, we obtain $V\otimes V=V_6\oplus 3V_4\oplus 2V_3\oplus 4V_2\oplus 2V_1\oplus 3V_0$ so the answer should be $3$.

Comment: I just realised that you assumed $B$ is symmetric so the answer I wrote was not correct, though it is true that there is a $3$-dimensional fixed subspace of *all* bilinear forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, that "annoying complex conjugate" really is a problem.  For example, consider the standard representation $V$ of $SU(3)$.  The dual of this representation is isomorphic to the conjugate $\overline{V}$, and is *not* isomorphic to $V$.

Then the representation $V\oplus \overline{V}$ of $SU(3)$ has a symmetric bilinear form $B$ for which $V$ and $\overline{V}$ are not B-orthogonal.  Namely, one can define $B(v_1,v_2) = B(f_1,f_2) = 0$ for all $v_1,v_2\in V$ and $f_1,f_2\in \overline{V}$ and $B(f,v) = B(v,f) = f(v)$.

This is $SU(3)$-invariant:  for $g\in SU(3)$, we have $B(gv,gf) = (gf)(gv) = f(g^{-1}gv) = f(v) = B(v,f)$.

Clearly, $B$ is non-zero, so with respect to $V$, the non-isomorphic representations $V$ and $\overline{V}$ are not orthogonal.

All that said, for $G = SU(2)$ we get lucky:  all representations are self-dual.    Said another way, if $V$ is any representation of $SU(2)$, then its dual representation $\overline{V}$ *is* isomorphic to $V$.  The proof is easy based on what you already know: it's enough to prove it when $V$ is irreducible.  But then $\overline{V}$ is irreducible of the same dimension, so $V\cong \overline{V}$.  In terms of your calculation, the key is the following:  there is a matrix $B\in SU(2)$ with the property that $BAB^{-1} = \overline{A}$ for every $A\in SU(2)$.

How do we see this is true?  Just use $B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and use the fact that every $A\in SU(2)$ is of the form $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ -\overline{b} & \overline{a}\end{bmatrix}$ with $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$.

The upshot of all this is that for $SU(2)$, $\rho(\overline{A}) = \rho(BAB^{-1}) = \rho(B)\rho(A)\rho(B)^{-1}$, so $\rho(B)$ acts as an intertwining map.  Thus, you *can* use Schur's Lemma to conclude that any symmetric bilinear form $B$ on $V = V_3\oplus V_1\oplus V_0$ is diagonal, in the sense that $B(V_i,V_j) = 0$ for $i\neq j$.

This reduces the problem to determining the symmetric bilinear forms on each $V_i$ specifically.  Of course, on $V_0$, any symmetric bilinear form works, and there's a single dimension worth of such forms.

What about $V_1$ and $V_3$?  Well,  I claim that the only symmetric bilinear form on either is the zero form.

Note that both $V_1$ and $V_3$ have a basis $e_1,...,e_{i+1}$ spanning irreps for which the maximal torus $S^1\subseteq SU(2)$.  Specifically, for $X = \operatorname{diag}(e^{i\theta}, e^{-i\theta})$ we have $Xe_1 = e^{i\theta} e_1$ and $Xe_2 = e^{-i\theta}e_2$ for $V_1$.  For $V_2$, we have in addition $Xe_3 = e^{3i\theta} e_3$ and $Xe_4 = e^{-3i\theta} e_4$.

Then invariance implies that $B(e_i,e_i) = B(Xe_j, Xe_j) = B(e^{\mu_j i\theta} e_j, e^{\mu_j i\theta}) = e^{2\mu_j i\theta} B(e_j,e_j)$, where $\mu_j\in \{\pm 1,\pm 3\}$.  Thus, we conclude that $(1-e^{2\mu_j i\theta})B(e_j,e_j) = 0$ for all $\theta$, which easily implies that $B(e_j, e_j) = 0$.

What about $B(e_j,e_k)$ for $j\neq k$?

First, focus on the case of $V_1$, so we just have an $e_1$ and $e_2$.  Here, we can use the matrix $Y = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta  & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$.  Then we have $$B(e_1,e_2) = B(Ye_1, Ye_2) = B(\cos\theta e_1 - \sin\theta e_2, \sin\theta e_1 + \cos\theta e_2) = \cos^2\theta B(e_1,e_2) -\sin^2\theta B(e_2,e_1) = (\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta)B(e_1,e_2).$$

Since this is true for all $\theta$, we must conclude $B(e_1,e_2) = 0$, so $B$ is identically $0$ for $V_1$.

What about for $V_3$?

Well, for $j=1,2$ and $k=3,4$, one can again use $X$ to see that $B(e_j,e_k) = 0$ for these options.

Thus, we are left with determining $B(e_1,e_2)$ and $B(e_3,e_4)$. If we take $Y$ with $\theta = \pi/2$, then we find that $Ye_1 = e_2$ and $Ye_2 = -e_1$.  Let me do the first calculation, just so we are on the same page.  We are going to think of $V_3$ as being spanned by the complex polynomials $z^3, z^2 w, zw^2, w^3$, where $g\in SU(2)$ acts as $g \ast f(z,w) = f( g^{-1} (z,w))$, where we think of $(z,w)$ as a column vector.

For $f(z,w) = zw^2$, we find $X\ast f (z,w) = f(e^{-i\theta} z, e^{i\theta} w) = e^{i\theta} f(z,w)$, so $zw^2$ corresponds to $e_1$.  (A similar calculation shows that $z^2 w$ corresponds to $e_2$.

Then for $f(z,w) = zw^2$, $Yf(z,w) = f(Y^{-1}(z,w)) = f(-w,z) = (-w)(z)^2 = -z^2 w = e_2$.  Thus, $Ye_1 = e_2$ as claimed.

But then, so $B(e_1,e_2) = B(Ye_1, Ye_2) = B(e_2, -e_1) = -B(e_1,e_2),$ so $B(e_1,e_2) = 0$.

The calculation for $B(e_3,e_4)$ is analogous, and I leave it for you.

Thus, we conclude that $B = 0$ on $V_1$ and $V_3$.

Summarizing, the final answer is that the space of symmetric bilinear forms invariant under the $SU(2)$ action is $1$-dimensional.

Comment: These calculations are a part of a much larger story.  For example, $V_i$ has no invariant non-zero symmetric bilinear forms when $i$ is odd (and a similar proof would work), but it *does* have invariant non-zero anti-symmetric bilinear forms.  Similarly, when $i$ is even, there are invariant symmetric bilinear forms, but no non-zero antisymmetric forms.  This turns out to be intimately tied to the fact that $V_i$ is the complexification of a real rep when $i$ is even, and it can be turned into a quaternionic rep when $i$ is odd.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was really insightful!!